# Does free disk space actually help mac performance?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, performance

Anyone will tell you that freeing disk space will make your mac faster - specially noticeable if your disk is almost full.

I don't *know* if that's true. Is it? And why, exactly?

I just don't see how can having more or less free disk space make my browsing/gaming/writing/etc faster. I mean, it's just... uh... space?

Comment: browsing/gaming/writing/etc needs free space to write too file. Not having enough means it cannot write it from virtual memory to file for example. Your operating system needs the same. I cannot find the apple recommendation of how much disk memory to keep free for operations. But it more about having the right amount than more. see the brief answer here http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/71960/17128

Comment: For one, it probably makes the filesystem faster if there are fewer files. Only speculation.